# Onlick listview to display object in android

Tags: android, listview, layout, onclick

Im new to android and trying to learn as I go. But im working on an app that displays an rss feed. So far I have parsed and displayed in a list view.

The list displays a title, description and date.

I am looking to make it so the title is a button, which on clicked displays the list item.

Here is my code that is relevant

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);  

List<Weather> weather= null;  
try
{
    // Get the data from the XML stream as a string
    result =  sourceListingString(sourceListingURL);

    XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();  
    weather = parser.parse(new StringReader ( result ));
    ArrayAdapter<Roadwork> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<Weather>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, roadworks);  
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

and here is my main layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".WeatherProject" >  

    <ListView  
        android:id="@+id/listView"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  

    </ListView>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you implemented you own adapter. If not implement your own adapter.

In adapter in getView() method you can set listener for title button and open the list

```
 Button buttonTitle = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        buttonTitle .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                //open the list item
            }
        });
```